# right margin cutting my page content

Tags: visualforce, html, style

i am rendering the vf page as pdf. but the pdf is cutting from right side. i have used the html as below-

```
<head>
   <style>
       body { font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS';
            }
   </style>
</head>
```

[image]

as shown in above pdf texts are cutting from right side

Comment: Please add some more details or screenshot with your question. Nobody can help using above details.

Comment: Can you post the code also